# Still 1000 hours of lifetime

Tags: design, manufacturing, lamp, incandescent, obsolescence

I am familiar with the famous Phoebus cartel of the companies Osram, Philips and GE, but this cartel began its operation in 1924 and lasted at most to the World War II. In the second half of the 20th century and in this century too, how is it that the present manufacturers of incandescent light bulbs still use the designs that are to last for around 1000 hours (even though many competitors unbounded to the cartel arrived in present era)? (This applies perhaps to other types such as CFL - they are also near the 1000 h limit.) Is there some well documented contemporary economical argument or business plan of some company that proves that a deviation from the established manufacturing practice would result in financial loss?

Can you refer to some modern designs or actual patents (although maybe not for free use) to incandescent light bulbs of notably longer lifetime that would be said to be withdrawn from manufacture for unprofitability? (opponents of planned obsolescence often refer that these designs exist, however without evidence)

Or is the lightbulb near its design limits?

For the sake of argument, let's stick just to the class of household lightbulbs (e.g. 60 W, 230 V, 500 lm).

Comment: I believe that this question is off-topic for EE.SE. It is inviting discussion about the industry, and it does not fit inside of the scope of the website.

Answer (score 5):

The (now obsolescent) conventional tungsten-filament consumer incandescent bulbs have a trade-off between life and efficiency.

The longer you make the bulb last for (by running the filament cooler) the less efficient the bulb is, so the higher the lifetime cost of the electricity required to illuminate it.

The light also becomes redder the cooler the filament runs, which is usually undesirable.

According to [this](https://greenlivingideas.com/2015/02/19/the-true-cost-of-light-bulbs-led-cfl-incandescent/) reference (and based on their assumptions of energy cost and bulb cost) more than 95% of the cost of using a 60W incandescent bulb is energy. If you ignore the cost and inconvenience of replacing bulbs, it seems we're actually on the wrong side of the trade-off at the typical 1200 hours life.

Comment: However, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Light_output_and_lifetime suggests that, for instance, if you increase the efficiency by about 10%, you'll cut the lifetime in half. At, say, 10 hrs/day, that cuts lifetime from 4 months to 2.

Comment: I guess optimum would be where light bulb replacement cost == electricity cost. Maybe, if not for the evil cartel, we would have had light bulbs with 10 or 20 filaments and selector switches to pick the next as they burned out.

Comment: Where I grew up, the electric monopoly gave out free lightbulbs on an exchange basis .  A retail store owner decoded to start selling light bulbs then sued them for unfair competition.   I should decide to start a private firehouse.